# Unique continuation from the boundary for inhomogeneous elliptic pde

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Let $Lu = f$ be satisfied on a bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with **smooth** boundary $\partial \Omega$, where $L$ is a strongly elliptic second order differential operator with real analytic coefficients in the interior $\Omega$. $u$ and $f$ are real analytic in the interior $\Omega$ and both are smooth up to the boundary, with zero Dirichlet boundary data $u|_{\partial \Omega} = f|_{\partial \Omega} = 0$. Suppose in addition we assume that $u$ satisfies zero Neumann data $ \frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}|_{\partial  \Omega} = 0$.

I am looking for references which give unique continuation results like $u = f = 0$. I am not sure if we need additional restrictions on $L$ to ensure such a conclusion (I am happy with references that say something about $L = \Delta$). Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Aronszajn, N.
A unique continuation theorem for solutions of elliptic partial differential equations or inequalities of second order. 
J. Math. Pures Appl. (9) 36 (1957), 235–249.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu I cannot seem to find the Aronszajn paper anywhere online. Is it a particular result there that you are referring to, or is it a general technique that I can may be locate somewhere else? Thanks a lot !

Comment: I have access only to hardcopies of the journal. Read the MathSciNet review. It describes  precisely Aronszajn's result. https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/pdf/92067.pdf?mx-pid=92067&pg1=INDI&r=26&s1=27355&sort=Newest&vfpref=html

Comment: I also don't have access to the named paper, but from "Koch and Tataru - Carleman Estimates and Unique Continuation for Second Order Parabolic Equations with Nonsmooth Coefficients" it is apparent that a non-zero source term ($f$ in your case) is usually not considered in elliptic PDE unique continuation literature. Maybe there is some common trick to transfer such results to non-zero source term case but I am not aware of it. Also, the table on page 3 in the Koch paper suggests that the results in the Aronszajn paper named above are only for $n \geq 3$. This is lifted in other papers.